# Capturing group in java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I was working around java regular expression, but according to some examples I found for groups like below are being confused. So could anybody illustrate about the regular expression which are given by,

```
(?<!\d) and (?!\d)
```

I understood:

```
\d for digit
? for one or zero
! for not
```

What would be the about above groups mean? Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude, this is not how this site is meant to be used.  There's a very good tutorial on **[this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)**, among many others, all just a Google away.

Answer (score 5):

The expressions `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` are a "negative look behind" and a "negative look ahead". They are negative, zero-width assertions, *not* capturing groups.

The expression `(?<!\d)` asserts that the previous character is *not* a digit.
The expression `(?!\d)` asserts that the next character is *not* a digit.

Although they *look* like groups, that is just that the syntax that uses brackets.

Incidentally, they could be expressed as positive look arounds `(?<=^|\D)` and `(?=\D|$)`

Comment: `(?!\d)` means this position is not followed by a digit--either the next character is a non-digit or there *is* no next character.  `(?=\D)` means there *is* a next character and it's a non-digit.  They're not equivalent.  And this is why we should direct posters of bone-basic questions like this to a tutorial.  I know *you* understand how lookarounds really work, but describing them correctly for newbies is not easy.

Comment: @AlanMoore good point - I was trying to be a smarty-pants with the "equivalent" positives. I've fixed them now by adding alternate start/end. Probably should have just left them out :/

Answer (score 0):

`(?<!X)` := X, via zero-width negative lookbehind

`(?!X)` := X, via zero-width negative lookahead

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html